# Spectral Norm of block diagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd, spectral-norm

I was reading a proof utilizing some property of the spectral norm, but fail to understand some steps. The part of the proof goes like,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left\|\left[\begin{array}{cc}{\sin ^{2} \Theta} & {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} \\ {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} & {-\sin ^{2} \Theta}\end{array}\right]\right\| =& \max _{1 \leq i \leq r}\left\|\left[\begin{array}{cc}{\sin ^{2} \theta_{i}} & {-\cos \theta_{i} \sin \theta_{i}} \\ {-\cos \theta_{i} \sin \theta_{i}} & {-\sin ^{2} \theta_{i}}\end{array}\right]\right\|\\[0.5cm]
= &\max _{1 \leq i \leq r}\left\|\sin \theta_{i}\left[\begin{array}{cc}{\sin \theta_{i}} & {-\cos \theta_{i}} \\ {-\cos \theta_{i}} & {-\sin \theta_{i}}\end{array}\right]\right\|\\[0.5cm]
=& \max _{1 \leq i \leq r}\left|\sin \theta_{i}\right|
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $|| \cdot||$ means the spectral norm.

$\sin ^{2}\Theta$ and $-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta$ are diagonal matrix with $\sin^2\theta_i$ and $-\cos\theta_i\sin\theta_i$ as its diagonal elements.

Can anyone help me to explain these few steps?

Comment: You can create a permutation matrix P such that  $B = P^{-1} A P$ is a block diagonal matrix with 2x2 blocks of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \sin^2\theta_i & -\cos\theta_i \sin \theta_i \\  -\cos\theta_i \sin \theta_i & -sin\theta_i \end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ is your original matrix.  Then the spectral norm of $B$ is the spectral norm of $A$ and it is also the maximum of the spectral norm of the 2x2 blocks along its diagonal.

Comment: Thank you , by the way, can I know the condition that when there exists a permutation matrix p that allow us to do this transform?

Comment: I think that if have a square matrix of size $rn$ by $rn$ consisting of diagonal $r$ by $r$ matrices, then you can find a permutation that converts the whole thing into a block diagonal matrix with $r$ blocks of size $n$ by $n$ along the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that
$$
P\pmatrix{
{\sin ^{2} \Theta} & {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} \\ {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} & {-\sin ^{2} \Theta}
}P^T = \pmatrix{M_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && M_r}
$$
where 
$$
M_i = \pmatrix{\sin^2 \theta_i & - \sin \theta_i \cos \theta_i
\\ - \sin \theta_i \cos \theta_i & - \sin \theta_i}.
$$
From there, we have
$$
\left\|\pmatrix{
{\sin ^{2} \Theta} & {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} \\ {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} & {-\sin ^{2} \Theta}
}\right\| = \\
\left\|P\pmatrix{
{\sin ^{2} \Theta} & {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} \\ {-\cos \Theta \sin \Theta} & {-\sin ^{2} \Theta}
}P^T\right\| = \\ 
\left\|\pmatrix{M_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && M_r}\right\| = 
\max_{1 \leq i \leq r} \|M_i\|.
$$

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for you help, can I know the condition that when there exists a permutation matrix p that allow us to do this transform?

Comment: Any block matrix whose blocks are diagonal can be rearranged to produce a [block-diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) matrix